# Unable to update react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to push new object into the react state, but the array state always return empty.

This is my **react state**:

```
this.state = {

          formname: '',
          newform : [],
          formField: {},
          formsCollection: []
        };
```

**Object result from state `formField`:**

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, formname: "form 1"}
  0: {type: "text", label: "First Name", title: "", name: "", uniquekey: "", …}
  1: {type: "", label: "Last Name", title: "", name: "", uniquekey: "", …}
  formname: "form 1"
  __proto__: Object
}
```

**Form onSubmit() handler function that is updating states:**

```
onSubmit= (e) => 
    {   
      e.preventDefault();

      const finalData = {formname: this.state.formname, ...this.state.newform};

      let formField = Object.assign(this.state.formField, finalData);

      this.setState({
        formField
      });

      console.log(this.state.formField, 'single form field');

      // const formsCollection = this.state.formsCollection.slice();



      // if(formsCollection.length){
      //   this.setState({ formsCollection: formsCollection });
      // }
      // else{
      //   formsCollection.push(formField);
      //   this.setState({ formsCollection : formsCollection });
      // }


      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        formsCollection: [...prevState.formsCollection, formField]
      }));

      console.log(this.state.formsCollection, 'forms collection are: ')

    };
```

Every time I click onSubmit(), it prints the single `formField` object to console, but not add new objects it to the `formsCollection` array. Also, I used both prevState and spread operator approach but in both cases, `console.log(this.state.formsCollection, 'forms collection are: ')` prints me an empty array everytime.

Please help to clear this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async so you won't see changes to the state values immediately. You can pass it a callback function where the updated state value is available:

```
this.setState({
  formField
}, () => console.log(this.state.formField, 'single form field'));
```

Another issue is that you're directly modifying your state with `Object.assign`, use functional form of `setState` instead:

```
 this.setState(state => ({
   ...state,
   formField: {
     formname: state.formname,
     ...state.newform
   }
 }));
```

Comment: I did used callback in setState(), but it still prints empty array []

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   this.setState(prevState => {
        prevState.formsCollection = [...prevState.formsCollection, formField];
        return prevState;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

setState works asynchronously, that's why you are not seeing the updated state, you can use a callback as

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    formsCollection: [...prevState.formsCollection, formField]
  }), () => {
     console.log(this.state.formsCollection, 'forms collection are: ')
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It is not printing even console statement

Comment: are you closing the setState parenthesis correctly ?

Comment: do you see any errors in browser's console, this seem to work for me, if possible create a Sandbox for your snippet

Comment: It's quite a big of nested data handling in my form so will be problem to create demo. If you could share yours?

Comment: Is there any way to change the code format to using conditions. Like, if state [] is empty, then push new objects otherwise return old state?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/classcomponent-sgscq this is a simple example when you click on Click here, data array in state is updated

Comment: it is difficult to help without reproducing the problem in this case, there are no errors in browsers console?